# hover mouse on capybara

Tags: selenium, mouseevent, capybara

I have a button on a page which only appears when hovering over a certain element. But I can't figure out how to emulate this and then click on the link so I can cucumber test it using Capybara and Selenium.

Answer (score 5):

You may want use a custom defined step for this, like:

```
When /^I click "([^"]*)" inside element "([^"]*)"$/ do |button, element_name|
```

Inside, you write something like:

```
begin
  evaluate_script("$('#{element_name}').trigger('mouseover')")
  rescue Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError
end
```

And then you click that button you want :)

Comment: sadly this does NOT work for css :hover based drop-downs... we need some sort of way to explicitly move a fake mouse around for certain things...

Comment: It should work imho. Try to be more explicit like this: evaluate_script("$('div#name > ul > li > a:contains(#{menu_name})').trigger('mouseover')"). Also, afaik selenium supports moving a cursor in x,y dimensions, but this is not fun ;)

Comment: socjopata, what capybara driver are you using and are you SURE you're using css :hover and not javascript or jquery's .hover(...)?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to simulate "mouse hover" using Capybara + the Selenium driver. Try this code:

```
module Capybara
  module Node
    class Element
      def hover
        @session.driver.browser.action.move_to(self.native).perform
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Works for me with Selenium's Chrome and Firefox drivers. You may have  to wait for a fraction of a second after hovering before it responds. If it's still not working, use the `debugger` gem, insert a call to `debugger` in one of your Capybara tests, and then experiment with typing Selenium commands as you watch what is happening in the Chrome/FF browser window.